# Is "waiting times" correct?

Tags: grammatical-number

Is the plural correct in this sentence?

> [It should cut the time between initial examination and diagnosis, reducing **waiting times** before treatment.](http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/health/974661.stm)

Can I just say *waiting **time*** instead of *waiting **times***?

Comment: [Waiting times in the NHS](http://www.nhs.uk/choiceintheNHS/Rightsandpledges/Waitingtimes/Pages/Guide%20to%20waiting%20times.aspx) used in the general sense.

Comment: *The NHS Constitution says you have the right to access certain services commissioned by NHS bodies within maximum waiting times ...  Waiting times may vary between hospitals ... You can compare waiting times for hospitals other than your local ones to see if the waiting time is shorter elsewhere.* (NHS; See above.)

Answer (score 2):

*Times* is correct. A careful reader can see this difference.

The real waiting time varies from case to case, all the 'times' (i.e., the waiting time in respect of each individual case) can be effectively reduced.

Comment: But isn't time, its duration, uncountable? We've been waiting a long time, but we read some magazines, sent text messages, and drank a few (cups of) coffees to pass the time. Can we say **A waiting time**?

Comment: @Mari-LouA *The times they are achanging!* In the OP's case, the reference is to a certain criterion, the 'waiting time' in respect of a case. This measurement changes in value with each case. Your waiting time is different from mine; our waiting **times** are not the same. HTH.

Comment: *The times* refers to "the general state of affairs at a particular period" So we can have good times, hard times and difficult times. There's also "many/a lot of times" which refers to a succession of individual events. I think it is the noun adjunt **waiting** that is the key. Train times, bus times, etc they are used in the plural, so *waiting times* is perfectly acceptable. Your reply made me do some research of my own which helped me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using it as a general term I would suggest you use the singular. After all you have not seen fit to put 'examination' nor 'diagnosis' in the plural, so why 'waiting time'? Obviously if you were talking about six instances all with different 'waiting times' you would use the plural.

Comment: The quote comes from the BBC website, so it's unfair to criticize the OP.

Comment: @Mari-Lou I had no idea where it had come from. But it makes no difference who wrote it. If you are going to use the plural in 'waiting-times, why not say 'examinations' and 'diagnoses'?

Comment: I am talking about your answer: "After all *you* have not seen fit..." It's an unfair comment, suggesting that the OP is careless. It influenced me negatively. And ask the BBC why they didn't write the plural forms, not me! :)

Comment: @Mari-Lou. Also if they are going to use the plural, why do they say 'time' in the singular at the beginning of the sentence? The nouns in this piece are being used in the same way that we might say, 'When it comes to pies, I prefer apple to cherry'. We would not normally say 'apples' and 'cherries' because we are using them in a general sense. In exactly the same way one says 'The Burmese jungle contains elephant, tiger and much else besides'.

Comment: @Mari-Lou Well now I know it is the BBC who are the culprits I apologise to the OP and say that the BBC ought to know better!

Comment: I'm not so sure that the BBC is wrong here. Examination and diagnosis is in the singular, the reader identifies with the actions. Whereas "waiting times" sounds more *detached* and objective. That's my personal impression.

Comment: @Mari-Lou You have made me wonder. I suppose 'waiting times' is part of a separate clause. In truth I think you could argue for either. On my first run at this I rather overlooked the first 'time'. The fact that that is there in the singular could, I suppose make a case for 'waiting times', as it means the first part of the sentence is a complete thought in itself, and the final clause is separate. But I still see nothing wrong with waiting-time, singular. The apple-pie example applies. Incidentally I should have said 'When it come to pie', not 'pies'.

Comment: @Mari-Lou I meant 'When it comes to pie'! There's many a slip betwixt cup and lip. Or should it be 'lips'?